# Js crashing when adding multiple images from byte array

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, model-view-controller

`

```
@model List<PhotoModel>;

@foreach (var photo in Model)
{
    <img src="" id="@photo.Id" >
}


<script>
    
    @foreach (var photo in Model)
    {
        <text>
            var id = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@photo.Id))
            var bytes = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@photo.Bytes))
            let img = document.getElementById(id)
            img.src = "data:image/png;base64," + bytes;    
        </text>
    }
    
</script>
```

`

I build a marketplace like app, and for each post i have a picture, if i only have one offer, the picture shows with no problem, but when i add one more offer to the db, the js crashes

If you have a better solution or a fix for my problem please tell me

Comment: add some more details please

Comment: done, i added some code

Comment: your code is ok. but maybe the problem is related to the `base64` images. if you load more and more images, the size of base64 grows more, so the js fall into the crash. the best approach to solve this problem is to use image URLs instead of base64. keep the images on the server and use their URL address to load them. this approach leads to caching images by the browser and reduces the size of the load. also, you can use one of the js frameworks like Angular or React to help you implement lazy loading when displaying images. generally you should reduce size of data

Comment: previously i used image URL, but since this it s a marketplace like project, i would like the user to load an image, like a profile picture on facebook or a post in instagram

Comment: but is still very strange that it crashes, and i dont have like 1000 pictures so it has a reson, if i add one even in 4k and another one in 4pixels it crashes

Comment: there is no problem that you keep the user's images server side. did the problem exist when you use the image URLs?

Comment: the problem didnt exist, but is there an option to make an image url from the input tag of type file?

Comment: previously i just had an textbox for the image url

Comment: Finally found the issue, was the let img variable, it says that was already been declared when I had multiple images, changed it to var and it s working, I m a JS Noo, so...